# Substitution with modular arithmetic?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I was watching [this](https://youtu.be/j4KhCT6kJvY?list=PLP6PHJ8SLR6AA93UEXGaDFUDc8paCCsiD) video, and was curious how they were able to do the following:

$$m^e\ modN = c$$
$$c^d\ modN = m$$

Therefore,

$$m^{ed}modN = m$$

It's all simple algebra, but I wasn't sure how they were able to substitute $m^e$ for $c$ without including the $modN$. Is there a theory that allows us to do this?

I have never taken a course on number theory or modular arithmetic, just curious about the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $m^{ed} mod N = x$ i.e. $m^{ed} = Nk+x$

$m^e = Nk_1 + c$

$c^d = Nk_2+m$

$m^{ed} = (Nk_1+c)^d = Nk'+c^d = Nk'+Nk_2+m$

Substituting $k'+k_2=k$ we get $ m^{ed}= Nk+m$

So $m^{ed} mod N = m$